# How to check if an object implements an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface

How to check if some class implements interface? 
When having:

`Character.Gorgon gor = new Character.Gorgon();`

how to check if `gor` implements `Monster` interface?

```
public interface Monster {

    public int getLevel();

    public int level = 1;
}

public class Character {
    public static class Gorgon extends Character implements Monster {
        public int level;
        @Override
        public int getLevel() { return level; }

        public Gorgon() {
            type = "Gorgon";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Is the method `getLevel()` overridden in `Gorgon` correctly, so it can return `level` of new `gor` created?

Comment: I think you Need the instanceof keyword.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

For an instance

```
Character.Gorgon gor = new Character.Gorgon();
```

Then do

```
gor instanceof Monster
```

For a Class instance do

```
Class<?> clazz = Character.Gorgon.class;
Monster.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
```

Comment: How about method parameter `public void doSomething([Object implements Serializable] param)`? What's the right syntax for that?

Comment: Yeh, `...isAssignableFrom()`, the only way to determine a Gorgonite is a monster.

Answer (score 46):

Use

```
if (gor instanceof Monster) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This answer is useful for users who don't have any complex inner classes or that stuff. Good job.

Answer (score 35):

In general for `AnInterface` and `anInstance` of any class:

```
AnInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(anInstance.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method like `public void doSomething([Object implements Serializable])` you can just type it like this `public void doSomething(Serializable serializableObject)`. You can now pass it any object that implements Serializable but using the `serializableObject` you only have access to the methods implemented in the object from the Serializable interface.