# How can I compare objects using instanceof but Interface types (not passing exact class name.)

Tags: java, interface, compare, delegation, instanceof

```
public interface Component{}

public class AppManager {


  public void doWork(){
    SomeComponent comp = new SomeComponent ();
    AddComponentToList(comp);

  }

  public void AddComponentToList(Component compo){
     componentList.add(compo);
  }

  /* Give me the component I want. */
  public Component getComponent(Component comp){
    for (Component component : getComponentList()) {

        if (component instanceof comp) {
          return component;  
        }

    }


  }

   private ArrayList<Component> componentList  = new ArrayList<Component>();

}

public class SomeComponent implements component {

  public void MyMethod() {

     appManager.getComponent(SomeComponent );
  }


  public void setAppMnger(AppManager appm){
     this.appManager = appm;
  }

  private AppManager appManager ;
}
```

In Above code AppMnger is having a list of components. Components are communicating each other. So if one component want to know another component instance it call the AppMnger getComponent(comp) method. But I get an error when I use instanceof operator. I don't want each component to want compare the list but I want to delegate that task to AppMnger because he is the one who knows about components it created.
Amy thought?

Comment: Side comment - I'd strongly advise you to avoid removing vowels for the sake of brevity like this. "AppManager" or even "ApplicationManager" are better names than "AppMnger"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165887/how-to-check-if-some-class-implements-interface

Comment: There are multple questions you might be trying to ask about the relationship between `component` and `comp`, such as "Do they have the same class?",  or "Is there any interface they both implement?", or "Do they both implement any of this set of interfaces?". All those questions could be answered given two references. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to check and find from componentList  the exact concrete class instance that I want. I am passing appMnger.getComponent(SomeComponent); and I want to find the SomeComponent instance from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should redesign `getComponent` to take a `Class<? extends Component>` rather than a `Component`. Then you can use [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public Component getComponent(Class<? extends Component> componentClass) {
    for (Component component : getComponentList()) {
        if (componentClass.isInstance(component)) {
           return component;  
        }
    }
    return null; // Or throw an exception, potentially.
}
```

And `SomeComponent` would use:

```
appManager.getComponent(SomeComponent.class);
```

If you *really* wanted to use an instance, you could overload the method like this:

```
public Component getComponent(Component existingComponent) {
    return getComponent(existingComponent.getClass());
}
```

EDIT: If you actually only want to check for the *exact* class, you don't want `instanceof`-like behaviour - you just want:

```
public Component getComponent(Class<? extends Component> componentClass) {
    for (Component component : getComponentList()) {
        if (componentClass == component.getClass()) {
           return component;  
        }
    }
    return null; // Or throw an exception, potentially.
}
```

I would still suggest using this method signature though - it would feel very odd to have to already *have* an instance of a component in order to *find* a component of the type you want.

Comment: hi jon, I try to use first option and it gave me error about can't find the return statement.

Comment: @user2771655: Fixed - it was a problem in your original pseudo-code which I hadn't spotted.

Comment: OK. That made me another problem. Why it doesn't find the return statement inside the if block?

Comment: @user2771655: It does - but if a method has a non-void return type, then you can't get to the end of the method without returning something. Consider the case where there are no components at all, or more generally if there are no components matching the specified type - what do you want to happen then?

Comment: I receive this error when passing the SomeComponent.class to getComponent()
"The method getComponent(Class<? extends Component>) in the type ApplicationManager is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: Jon, Please ignore above comment. I've made a mistake.

Comment: How can I use this with prior java 1.5 version.

Comment: Well you can't use generics at all before Java 1.5, or the enhanced for loop. You could still call `iterator()` though, and just cast the result of `next()` each time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the class to match exactly (List != ArrayList) then use this:

```
if (comp.getClass().equals(component.getClass())) ...
```

If you want it to work exactly like instanceof (List => ArrayList) then you can try this:

```
if (comp.getClass().isInstance(component)) ...
```

Comment: Based on the clarifying comment "I want to check and find from componentList the exact concrete class instance that I want. I am passing appMnger.getComponent(SomeComponent); and I want to find the SomeComponent instance from the list." I think the first alternative is the correct answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Yup, I've edited my answer to indicate that too. The reference to `instanceof` in the question is misleading :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess previous answers by Black,max and Jon are sufficient enough for your comparison part , for the  "I don't want each component to want compare the list but I want to delegate that task to AppMnger because he is the one who knows about components it created. Amy thought?"  you can try using the visitor design pattern .